# Error "A circular dependency is detected for bundle" on AWS Lightsail, works fine in XAMP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii2, amazon-lightsail

I have a ready made classifieds script I bought off the web, which works fine in XAMP on my pc, but when I upload it on an AWS Lightsail all I get is an error.

I tried uploading it multiple times via ftp, both single files and unzipping directly through SSH to avoid corruption issues or something, result is always the same. I checked 10 times that the mysql info is correct, reimported the db multiple times. Not that it seems DB related (if I put that info wrong it WILL show a database error instead of this one).
The code/script seller is extremely slow and unresponsive. I'd ask for a refund if I had alternatives.

In the browser I get:

```
`An internal server error occurred.`
The apache log throws:

> [Wed Jul 10 20:34:15.449369 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19005:tid
> 139671380154112] [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:53449] AH01071: Got error 'PHP
> message: An Error occurred while handling another
> error:\nyii\\base\\InvalidConfigException: A circular dependency is
> detected for bundle 'frontend\\assets\\ThemeAsset'. in
> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php:295\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetBundle.php(125):
> yii\\web\\View->registerAssetBundle('frontend\\\\assets...')\n#1
> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/frontend/views/layouts/main.php(29):
> yii\\web\\AssetBundle::register(Object(yii\\web\\View))\n#2
> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(348):
> require('/opt/bitnami/ap...')\n#3
> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(257):
> yii\\base\\View->renderPhpFile('/opt/bitnami/ap...', Array)\n#4
> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(399):
> yii\\base\\View->renderFile('/opt/bitnami/ap...', Array,
> Object(frontend\\controllers\\SiteController))\n#5
> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(385):
> yii\\base\\Controller->renderConte...\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

As in error is write , you have a Circular dependency error . I think  this maybe cause because you dont have  installed "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:dev-master"

Try to do it   in your AWS

> composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:dev-master"